# Repeat Title and Date R Markdown PDF

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown

I am struggling what what is likely a trivial markdown matter. I am hoping to avoid YAML and additional header templates and such if I can. So my question is straightforward and I welcome your feedback. For an R Markdown knitted as a PDF, how can I repeat the title and date on each printed page?

Alternatively I am happy to use headers using the '#' syntax. But if I can use the title parameters that would be preferred.

The Header thus far:

```
---
title: "Dashboard"
date: '`r paste(Sys.Date(), " to ", Sys.Date()+14)`'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Calibri
geometry: margin=1cm
classoption: landscape
params:
  set_title: !r test_title
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\huge}
  - \posttitle{\end{flushleft}}  
  - \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}}
  - \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}  
  - \predate{\begin{flushleft}\large}
  - \postdate{\end{flushleft}}  
---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [rmarkdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/document-metadata.html):

> When a Rmd document is compiled, all of its metadata in the YAML section
>   will be stored in the list object `rmarkdown::metadata`. You can use this object
>   in your R code. For example, `rmarkdown::metadata$title` gives you the title
>   of the document.